# Changing keyboard layout

Tags: linux, centos, keyboard-layout, locale

I want to change the keyboard layout from US to UK through the terminal on my Linux machine. I'm running CentOS 6.4. I have tried using the `loadkeys uk` method, but it doesn't change the layout. It is still US.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
loadkeys uk
```

As root should work.. Maybe the `uk` layout isn't installed on your system?

Or try to open **`/etc/sysconfig/keyboard`** and replace `KEYTABLE="us"` by `KEYTABLE="uk"`, a reboot will be necessary.

Comment: yups that worked good ! i also changes the LAYOUT="gb" and everything works good ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal try

su -
gnome-keyboard-properties

OR

if the default Gmone2 
system /administration / keyboard