# CentOS 6.4 console keyboard layout hotswitch

Tags: centos, keyboard-layout, console, centos-6, keymap

On an X-server-less CentOS 6.4 box (so no `setxkbmap`) I share with another person, the other person's name is much easier to type in a particular keymap.  Ideally, there would be a way, on-the-fly, to switch keymaps while sitting at the login prompt at the physical machine.  How can this be done?

If it can't be done, how can I at least set it up so I can use my own keymap automatically once I log in?  [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/668269/changing-keyboard-layout) seems to set the console keyboard in a system-wide way via config file editing (and unfortunately `sudo loadkeys...` and `loadkeys...` seemed to have no effect for me despite saying 'Loading...'.)

I also tried `yum install system-config-keyboard.x86_64` and running `system-config-keyboard` as root.  No effect, it spits out 'Loading...' just like loadkeys does, but doesn't change the behaviour of my keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard`, that affects the console, but not ssh sessions, which is why I wasn't noticing the change.